# Why does inline-block remove spaces between words?

Tags: html, css

[Result has no space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmnCH.png)

[Code has a space between words.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1THK.png)

How do I fix this? I need to use inline-block (or any inline display) because my animation won't work without it.
[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA12T.png)

This is the javascript for the animation.

```
const text = document.querySelector("h1");
    const strText = text.textContent;
    const splitTxt = strText.split("");
    text.textContent = "";
    for(let i=0; i < splitTxt.length; i++){
        text.innerHTML += "<span>"+ splitTxt[i] + "</span>";
    }

    let char = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(onTick, 50);

    function onTick() {
        const span = text.querySelectorAll('span')[char];
        span.classList.add('fade');
        char++;
        if(char === splitTxt.length) {
            complete();
            return;
        }

    }

    function complete() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
```

Edit: I fixed this by putting a `&nbsp;`in between the letters.

Comment: As per the screenshot attached, it looks like your code is inside h1, and css is applied on span? Can you provide an actual example to run code snippet

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for the confusion, what's happening is that I have some Javascript which is turning each character of the text into a span and animating it.

Comment: Can you edit the HTML and CSS into the question as plain text the same way you did your JavaScript code, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want every word of the h1 to be inside of a span tag, you should do the split with a whitespace, like this:

```js
    const splitTxt = strText.split(" ");
```

In your code you have the quotes inside the split function without the space between, and that will cause that every character to be in a span.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I already fixed the problem by adding a `&nbsp;` in between the words.

Answer (score -1):

You mean this?

```css
header {
  position:relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    myText
  </h1>
</header>
```

Comment: The problem is that that makes the text vertical in my case.